# Evaluate $C_0+4C_1+7C_2+...+ (3n+1)C_n$

Tags: combinatorics

Evaluate $C_0+4C_1+7C_2+...+ (3n+1)C_n$
where $C_n$ are binomial coefficients as we know.

I get the answer as $3n2^{n-1}+2^n$ .am I correct? Please somebody ensure me please. thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe you may know, but the binomial coefficients that I know of have **two** indices, not one, and are written $\binom nk$. In other words your question does not seem to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

$$T_{r+1}=(3r+1)\binom nr=3r\frac{n!}{(n-r)! r!}+\binom nr \text{where}\space 0\le r\le n$$

Now,  $$r\frac{n!}{(n-r)! r!}=r\frac{n!}{\{n-1-(r-1)\}!) r(r-1)!} \text{if} \space  r\ge1$$

$$r\frac{n!}{(n-r)! r!}=n\frac{(n-1)!}{\{n-1-(r-1)\}!) (r-1)!} =n\binom{n-1}{r-1}$$

$$\sum_{0\le r\le n}(3r+1)\binom nr$$
$$=3n\sum_{0\le r\le n}\binom{n-1}{r-1}+\sum_{0\le r\le n}\binom nr$$
$$=3n\sum_{1\le r\le n}\binom{n-1}{r-1}+\sum_{0\le r\le n}\binom nr$$
$$=3n(1+1)^{n-1}+(1+1)^n=3n2^{n-1}+2^n=2^{n-1}(3n+2)$$

Comment: that's mean I am right.thanks for your help.

Comment: @rama, welcome. Btw, how have you calculated?