# How to find sum of $n$ terms of $3C_1+7C_2+11C_3+\cdots$

Tags: combinatorics

let $n\in \mathbb N$ be fixed and let $0\leq k\leq n$ Let $C_k$ denote number of ways of choosing $k$ objects from n distinct objects. How to find sum of $n$ terms of

$$3C_1+7C_2+11C_3+\cdots$$

I thought of using the identity $(1+x)^n=C_0+C_1x+C_2x^2+\cdots+C_nx^n$ but that did not yield anything.How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\binom nk$ denote the number of ways of choosing $k$ objects from $n$ objects. Setting $x=1$ in the binomial identity
$$(1+x)^n=\binom n0+\binom n1x+\binom n2x^2+\binom n3x^3+\cdots$$
and subtracting $1$, we get
$$2^n-1=\binom n1+\binom n2+\binom n3+\cdots.$$
Differentiating the binomial identity, we get
$$n(1+x)^{n-1}=\binom n1+2\binom n2x+3\binom n3x^2+\cdots.$$
Multiplying by $4$, we get
$$4n(1+x)^{n-1}=4\binom n1+8\binom n2x+12\binom n3x^2+\cdots.$$
Setting $x=1$ in the last identity,
$$4n2^{n-1}=4\binom n1+8\binom n2+12\binom n3+\cdots.$$
Subtracting the last identity from the second one,
$$4n2^{n-1}-(2^n-1)=3\binom n1+7\binom n2+11\binom n3+\cdots,$$
that is,
$$3\binom n1+7\binom n2+11\binom n3+\cdots=(2n-1)2^n+1.$$

Comment: Thanks @bof your answer helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

For integer $k>0,$

$$(4k-1)\binom nk=4 k \frac{n\cdot(n-1)!}{\{(n-1)-(k-1)\}!\cdot k\cdot (k-1)!}-\binom nk$$

$$=4n\binom{n-1}{k-1}-\binom nk$$

Now, $\sum_{r=0}^m\binom mr=(1+1)^m$ for integer $m\ge1$

Comment: Where is the $n$ in the numerator please explain sir

Comment: @learningmaths,  $n! = n\cdot (n-1)!$ So, the answer $$=4(1+1)^{n-1}-(1+1)^n+1$$

Comment: ya dats true but one n is missing

Comment: @learningmaths, Thanks for your observation. So, the answer will be $$4n(1+1)^{n-1}-(1+1)^n+1$$

Comment: @learningmaths, related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282667/evaluate-c-04c-17c-2-3n1c-n and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013153/algebric-proof-for-the-identity-nn-12n-2-sum-k-1n-kk-1-n-choose-k